# How can I determine if a server has been migrated on google cloud services?

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Background:
I have a cluster of 3 linux VMs. They are running identical configurations and are load balanced via google's network load balancer.

Recently, I've noticed that the load on 1 of these machines is significantly higher than the others at all times. Not a spiked CPU, just 2x-3x load average consistently.

Audits of the servers have find no rootkit or malware. The process list is nearly identical. Memory usage is nominal on all machines. There is no excessive swapping. Writes to disk are all nominal.

From viewing the SQL numbers, the machines appear to be handling within .1% of the same traffic over the past 2 weeks.

Looking at cumulative CPU time (via top), I see that the mysql process as well as other long-running processes on this machine seem to have consumed about 70% more CPU time than on the other 2 machines (all restarted within an hour of each other 2 weeks ago). This has to have occurred over a 3 day period as that is when the CPU charts show the increased usage on this machine versus the others.

Additionally, I noticed what appears to be a spike of connections to this server via error logs. It occurred only once, but it was about the time the CPU issue seems to have begun.

Shutting down the server for several minutes via the cloud console seems to have remedied the issue - for now.

My current hypothesis is that the connection spike occurred due to a brownout caused by a live migration and that the CPU usage is higher because the new hypervisor is configured differently - most likely due to a hotfix for the Intel look ahead exploits.

Can anyone point me to a log that would show server migrations so I can confirm or rule out the live migration portion of this hypothesis?

Any other thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Hypervisor migrations are completely invisible to the guest VM, and invisible to you. Are you handling enough traffic that two or three milliseconds delay is something your application will notice and react that badly to?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, no, I doubt our application would notice a delay of only a couple of milliseconds. If live migrations are really that fast, color me impressed.

Comment: To be fair, it depends on how busy the VM is, but that's pretty typical in my experience. There's a very detailed description of KVM migration [on the Red Hat blog](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2015/03/24/live-migrating-qemu-kvm-virtual-machines/) (Google Compute is KVM-based).

Comment: @MichaelHampton, they're not particularly large machines. 2 vCPU, 7.5G RAM. The particular process I noticed spiking probably only gets 2-3 hits per second per server and runs 5-10 idle processes.

I guess I need to try and figure out if a CPU is patched for the look ahead exploits and go back to throwing darts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the metadata server from the VM to check whether a live migration is about to take place and get some advance notice (60 seconds before the event.)

You should query the `maintenance-event` attribute to find out when a live migration is about to happen.

[This page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#maintenanceevents) has instructions on how to query this attribute and a sample Python script that you can adapt to take some action in the case of a migration.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to determine what has already happened. If this continues to occur, it may be worth slapping together a monitiring daemon just to rule it out.